# SSRS Server Web Service using 2-Way SSL - Error : HTTP Error 403.7 – Forbidden

Tags: web-services, wcf, ssl, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have tried various configuration settings but still no luck
I’m getting the below error when I tried to run a report from SSRS server.

**HTTP Error 403.7 - Forbidden
The page you are attempting to access requires your browser to have a Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) client certificate that the Web server recognizes.**

**processing!ReportServer_0-2!1084!03/26/2015-13:21:18:: e ERROR: An exception has occurred in data set 'DistributionComponents'. Details: Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: Query execution failed for dataset 'xComponents'. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.XmlDP.XmlDPException: Failed to execute web request for the specified URL.
Forbidden: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. ---> System.Exception: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.**

### Setup:

[image]

### Configuration:

WCF Service:

In the WCF Service I have bindings configured as Transport, and the pretty much like described in the below article
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/348595/Use-Mutual-SSL-Authentication-in-WCF

I can browse to the service and view WSDL without no issues. I have also checked the WCF trace and no errors.

SSRS Web Service Configuration:

[image]

[image]

[image]

SSRS Web Service Data Source has been configured to execute the HTTPs WCF Web Service URL. 
SSRS also configured to use a valid SSL Certificate.

I can access the ReportsManager URL and View reports successfully using HTTPs URLs.

I have tried many configuration settings, including disabling the firewall and virus scans still no luck. I have also search on the Web but there is no much direction on this particular issue.

Can some please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be more precise I would have said the SSRS installed in the Native mode. Nevertheless I figured it out that this is not supported. In other words [2-Way SSL between SSRS (acting as a Client) and the WCF (Service) is not supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345223.aspx).